# Constructor not defined: [System.SelectOption].<Constructor>(String)

Tags: apex, describes

I am trying to save below class but getting the error at line:

```
options.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(fieldSetMemberObj.getFieldPath())), String.valueOf(fieldSetMemberObj.getLabel()));
```

I tried to convert this to string but still not working

```
    public class adssReportBuilder {
    public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> accfieldSetMemberList{get; set;}
    public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> pacfieldSetMemberList{get; set;}
    public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> confieldSetMemberList{get; set;}
    public string[] selectedFields {get; set;} 
    public adssReportBuilder(){
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> accfieldSetMemberList = readFieldSet('AccFieldSet','Account');
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> pacfieldSetMemberList = readFieldSet('PAFieldSet','ADSS_Platform_Account__c');
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> confieldSetMemberList = readFieldSet('ConFieldSet','Contact');
        selectedFields = new String[]{};
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getAccountFields() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember fieldSetMemberObj : accfieldSetMemberList){
            options.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(fieldSetMemberObj.getFieldPath())), String.valueOf(fieldSetMemberObj.getLabel())); 
        }     
        return options;         
    }

    public static List<Schema.FieldSetMember> readFieldSet(String fieldSetName, String ObjectName){
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GlobalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
        Schema.SObjectType SObjectTypeObj = GlobalDescribeMap.get(ObjectName);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult DescribeSObjectResultObj = SObjectTypeObj.getDescribe();
        //system.debug('====>' + DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName));
        Schema.FieldSet fieldSetObj = DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName);
        //List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fieldSetMemberList =  fieldSetObj.getFields();
        //system.debug('fieldSetMemberList ====>' + fieldSetMemberList);  
        return fieldSetObj.getFields(); 
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parentheses are not quite right. You have one extra after your `fieldPath`.

```
options.add(new SelectOption(
    String.valueOf(fieldSetMemberObj.getFieldPath()),
    String.valueOf(fieldSetMemberObj.getLabel())
));
```

Of note, those methods on `FieldSetMember` already return string, so you can make it less confusing by removing your calls to `String.valueOf`:

```
options.add(new SelectOption(
    fieldSetMemberObj.getFieldPath(),
    fieldSetMemberObj.getLabel()
));
```

Comment: Ahh, it was such a silly mistake. Thank you @adrian

Comment: Done, SFSE does not allow to accept immediately !!